# VueJS: class not being bound on button click

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have written a function that binds an `active` class to a popup when an image has been clicked. However, while the `expandedImageActive` and `expandedImage` data properties are updated correctly when `toggleExpand()` runs, the class isn't bound to the popup correctly. What am I doing wrong? Below is the relevant code (assuming `mainImage` has a value):

HTML

```vue
<section class="product__images">
    <div class="product__images-main">
        <a @click="toggleExpand(mainImage)">
        <img :src="mainImage.url" :alt="mainImage.description ? mainImage.description : product.title.value"  />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="popup" :class="{ active: expandedImageActive }">
        <div v-if="expandedImage">
            <a @click="toggleExpand()">close</a>
            <img :src="expandedImage.url" />
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

JS

```vue
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data () {
    return{
        mainImage: null,
        expandedImage: null,
        expandedImageActive: false
    }
}
methods: {
    toggleMainImage (image){
        this.mainImage = image;
    },
    toggleExpand (image){
        image ? this.expandedImage = image: this.expandedImage = null;
        this.expandImageActive = !this.expandImageActive;
        console.log(this.expandImageActive)
    }
}
})
```

Comment: There is a typo in your `toggleExpand`:  you are writing `expandImageActive` instead of `expandedImageActive`

Comment: My last two questions were both the result of typos. I think I'm just stupid at this point.